# How to completely remove git from a project?

Tags: git, symfony

I remove the `.git` folder from my project folder using `$ rm -rf .git`, but when I try to run the command `$ ./bin vendors install` (it's a symfony2 project), I get:

```
Installing/Updating symfony
M src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_table_layout.html.twig
"symfony" has local modifications. Please revert or commit/push them before running this command again.
```

But I can't commit anymore as `.git` does not exist now. But even if I create another Git repository and then make a commit, I have always the same message.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try reverting local modifications, like advised:

```
cd vendor/symfony
git checkout .
cd ../..
php bin/vendors install
```

You're supposed to have one repository per vendor, so deleting the repository of your project won't affect these repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are more than one git repository? Try the following to see if there are other git repositories in the project:

```
$ cd /your/project/root
$ find . -name .git
```

Also check the environment variable GIT_DIR.